# jQuery script have problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, news-ticker

I used this script that I found online ( https://codepen.io/erickarbe/pen/gyfFB )
but after the first loop it just gets stuck in the middle and goes back to the start, if you give it a look it doesnt work properly, if anyone could help me figure it out it would be great !

```
$jQuery.fn.liScroll = function(settings) {
  settings = jQuery.extend({
    travelocity: 0.03
  }, settings);     
  return this.each(function(){
    var $strip = jQuery(this);
    $strip.addClass("newsticker")
    var stripHeight = 1;
    $strip.find("li").each(function(i){
      stripHeight += jQuery(this, i).outerHeight(true); // thanks to Michael Haszprunar and Fabien Volpi
    });
    var $mask = $strip.wrap("<div class='mask'></div>");
    var $tickercontainer = $strip.parent().wrap("<div class='tickercontainer'></div>");                             
    var containerHeight = $strip.parent().parent().height();    //a.k.a. 'mask' width   
    $strip.height(stripHeight);         
    var totalTravel = stripHeight;
    var defTiming = totalTravel/settings.travelocity;   // thanks to Scott Waye     
    function scrollnews(spazio, tempo){
      $strip.animate({top: '-='+ spazio}, tempo, "linear", function(){$strip.css("top", containerHeight); scrollnews(totalTravel, defTiming);});
    }
    scrollnews(totalTravel, defTiming);             
    $strip.hover(function(){
      jQuery(this).stop();
    },
    function(){
      var offset = jQuery(this).offset();
      var residualSpace = offset.top + stripHeight;
      var residualTime = residualSpace/settings.travelocity;
      scrollnews(residualSpace, residualTime);
    });         
  });   
};

$(function(){
  $("ul#ticker01").liScroll();
});
```

Comment: `it just gets stuck in the middle and goes back to the start,` - what does? `if you give it a look it doesnt work properly` - why? what is it supposed to do? what does it do instead? the code does exactly what it is written to do - so saying "doesn't work properly" doesn't mean the code is wrong, it means you are using it for the wrong purpose ... "script i found online" - what were you looking for when you found that script? what makes you think someone elses script does what you want it to do? You need to supply **details**

Comment: alright, i want the text to scroll all the way over and over in a smooth way, what it does it just scroll all the way one time and after that it gets to the middle of the list and jumps to the start

Answer (score 0):

The only way I find that the following iterations differ from the first is that they stop at the end of the list as opposed to sliding all the way up the screen another time.

That is because when scrollnews calls itself recursively to restart, it assumes it just needs to travel literally the height it's told, ignoring the extra scrolling distance picked up when starting over with the extra positive offset. So, you'd want to change the scrollnews call to `scrollnews(totalTravel + containerHeight, defTiming)`

That may throw off the timing ratio they have set up, though.

Comment: When I added the containerHeight after the first loop it just stopped going on and stayed blank...

Comment: So you have this line? `$strip.animate({top: '-='+ spazio}, tempo, "linear", function(){$strip.css("top", containerHeight); scrollnews(totalTravel + containerHeight, defTiming);});`